# Javascript Array only put fish image where location = Yes

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working on an app using a dataset that tells where fish are located. In the dataset it will say Fishtype = No or Yes, I have it so the images appear, but they appear on every location, because its iterating through an array and as soon as it gets a 'Yes' it will put that fish in places even that say 'No'.

```
var locations = [

            ['1','-72.15148988','44.87974814','Brownington Pond','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','Yes','No','No','Yes','No','Yes','Yes','Yes','No','No'],
['2','-73.18239075','43.76844728','Burr Pond','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','Yes','Yes','No']]

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {

        var fishimages = '';
        if (locations[i][4] == 'Yes');
            {
                var fishimages = fishimages + '<img src="img/Bowfin.jpg">' + '<br>';
            }
        if (locations[i][5] == 'Yes');
            {
                var fishimages = fishimages + '<img src="img/Carp.jpg">' + '<br>';
            }

        var test = 'Water Body: ' + locations[i][3] + '<br>' + 'Fish:' + '<br>' + fishimages;
      infowindow.setContent(test);

      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
}
```

Comment: `in the loop` what loop?

Comment: hey @JaromandaX, I actually ment to say Array, its going through an array Updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolons after your `if` statements.

```
if (locations[i][4] == 'Yes');
```

should be

```
if (locations[i][4] == 'Yes')
```

They're terminating the conditional and then continuing into your braces like it was just a normal block of code.

Comment: Thanks @Tor! That was simpler than I thought haha works great now!

Comment: @Jeff I'll admit I stared at it longer than I care to admit before I noticed there were semicolons there!